# python matplotlib 2.x axis autolimit

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I've got a problem with matplotlib 2.x code not reproducing 1.x behaviour, when it comes to choosing the auto-limits on the axes. According to https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html , version 1.x axis rounding should be reproduced by the using the commands:

```
mpl.rcParams['axes.autolimit_mode'] = 'round_numbers'
mpl.rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0
mpl.rcParams['axes.ymargin'] = 0
```

But it doesn't. See the code below. My y values range from just above 5 to just below 50. When I run the code:

- with classic (version 1.x) behaviour (sys.argv[1]=="1"), the y axis ticks are 5 and 50.
- with version 2.x behaviour (sys.argv[1]=="2") the y axis ticks are 0 and 60.

Version 2.x rounding appears to be coarser. How do I reproduce version 1.x rounding?

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

if sys.argv[1]=="1":
    import matplotlib.style
    matplotlib.style.use('classic')
elif sys.argv[1]=="2":
    mpl.rcParams['axes.autolimit_mode'] = 'round_numbers'
    mpl.rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0
    mpl.rcParams['axes.ymargin'] = 0
else:
    raise Exception("param must be 1 or 2")

z = [49.0, 14.5, 6.0, 5.8]
steps = len(z)

plt.clf()
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6)) # Matplotlib 1.x default
plt.subplot(311)
plt.plot(range(steps), z)

plt.xlim(xmin=0, xmax=steps-1)
plt.xticks(range(steps))
ymin, ymax = plt.ylim()
plt.yticks([ymin, ymax])

plt.savefig("mpltest%s.pdf" % sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: python 2.7.14, matplotlib 2.1.0

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior on Python 2.7.2, matplotlib 2.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the number of ticks on the axes is different between the classic mode and the adapted rcParams.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mode = "classic" #"classic" #"modern"
if mode == "classic":
    plt.style.use('classic')
else:
    plt.rcParams['axes.autolimit_mode'] = 'round_numbers'
    plt.rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0
    plt.rcParams['axes.ymargin'] = 0

z = [49.0, 14.5, 6.0, 5.8]

plt.figure(figsize=(3,6))
plt.subplot(311)
plt.title("{} mode".format(mode))
plt.plot(range(len(z)), z)
```

[image]
[image]

Because of that different number of ticks, also the next "round number" is different. In classic mode it is `5` and `50`, in "modern" mode `0` and `60`.

The [changes to the defaults guide](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#number-of-ticks) states in the "number of ticks" section:

> The locator now includes an algorithm to estimate the maximum number of ticks that will leave room for the tick labels. [...] There is no way, other than using `mpl.style.use('classic')`, to restore the previous behavior as the default. [...] The algorithm used by `MaxNLocator` has been improved, and this may change the choice of tick locations ***in some cases***. This also affects `AutoLocator`, which uses `MaxNLocator` internally.

Here, you have run into exactly one of those "in some cases".

Comment: So there's no other way to do it except do the rounding myself? That's fine I guess, at least now I know.

Comment: It depends on how important this feature is to you. If you need it in a lot of cases it could be worthwhile digging for the old algorithm and implementing it by subclassing the locator. If you only need it a couple of times just setting the limits manually is definitely the way to go.