# How can I get old matplotlib version 1.5.1 interface?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I recently updated from matplotlib 1.5.1 to 2.2.3 with

```
$ pip install -U matplotlib
```

When showing plotted data with

```
>>> plt.show()
```

I could see plots displayed as shown in the attached picture "Output before update" before running the update from 1.5.1 to 2.2.3.
Because I didn't like the new interface of version 2.2.3 when displaying plots I switched back to the old version with

```
$ pip install matplotlib==1.5.1
```

Yet I'm still seeing a different interface when I show plots using the old matplotlib version (as you can see in the image "Output after update and return to the old version"), even though I returned to the old version of matplotlib I had used to generate the "Output before update".

You can check what I mean by "interface" when you type in your command line:

```
$ python
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot()
>>> plt.show()
```

You'll see the "interface" (in my case IPython) and an empty plot.

My questions are:
How do I display plots with the old output window again ("Output before update", see below)?
And why didn't the return to version 1.5.1 bring the old output window back as well?

Attached you find a comparison between the old output interface that I'd like to get back, and the new output using the same matplotlib version (slightly different data shown, but both plotted in default style, only with colors and markers manually set). The new output is blurry and thick, and the data points are very large as opposed to the old version, which I find much less aesthetic.

Output after update and return to the old version

[image]

Output before update

[image]

Picture of the "blurry" output window

[image]

Comment: Did you *uninstall* matplotlib 2.2.3 before installing 1.5?

Comment: If this is only about "style" you can also get the classic mode back as shown e.g. [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128166/python-matplotlib-2-x-axis-autolimit).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thank you, but I tried both. It doesn't bring back the old output window style

Comment: If you uninstall matplotlib, make sure the complete folder is removed from the `site-packages`. If you only change the style via `rcParams` this will not change the interface of course, only how the plot looks like (tickmarkers, colors, sizes etc).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes, it was removed from site-packages completely. I suspect this has something to do with another package that's displaying the data, not with matplotlib directly, but I don't know the inner workings of this.
I am using the Anaconda 2 distrubution for python 2.7, so I guess it's related to another package in Anaconda - is that possible?

Comment: There are two different things: (1) Uninstall/Reinstall, and (2) changing rcParams. (1) If you uninstall matplotlib and another package is able to create a matplotlib interface, that other package either *is* matplotlib, or matplotlib is still there and hasn't been removed. (2) Another package changing the matplotlib rcParams is perfectly possible though. I'm unsure which strategy you are talking about here.

Comment: So when I used uninstall in the command line as shown above, and checked in the site-packages folder, there were not traces of matplotlib left and I wasn't able to call the interface anymore.
When I updated and then (presumably) went back to the old version I originally had, the interface had changed, but I didn't change the rcParams. I kept plotting with the default parameters all along (i.e. I didn't use the style.use command to switch between different plotting styles)
Is that what you mean?

Comment: Not sure what the question is now, but if you did uninstall matplotlib and installed matplotlib==1.5.3 and the interface looks like you want it to look, that is exactly what you're after, right? If this is not what you see, better update the question with the exact steps you took (always in the order (a) action (I did...), (b) outcome (I saw), (c) expected outcome (I would have liked ...), else it's really hard to understand what you have done or not done and at which point you saw what.

Comment: I see; all steps I took are described in the original post, in the same order as described above. Before taking the first step, i.e. the update from 1.5.1 to 2.2.3 the output looked like as depicted in the attached picture "Output before update".
After having taken all steps described above, i.e. the update and the intstallation of the old version, 1.5.1, which encompassed the deinstallation of 2.2.3 automatically, I was expecting to see the old output "Output before update", but what I did see was the "Output after update and return to the old version".
What I want back is the first one.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I edited the post, I hope that clarifies the question

Comment: When you `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)`, what does it print?

Comment: >>> import matplotlib
>>> print(matplotlib.__version__)
1.5.1

Comment: Ok, what does `print(matplotlib.get_configdir())` print? It should be a folder on your disk. Can you navigate to that folder, make a backup and delete its content. Then restart the python interpreter / kernel and plot something again.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ok, followed all your instructions. Unfortunately, I still get the same result as before.
I don't know if that helps, but the output window the plots are shown in is an IPython panel. I used the Windows Power Shell command line to plot.
Could it be that IPython was also updated in the background during my update to matplotlib 2.2.3, and does not automatically revert to the old version upon uninstalling matplotlib 2.2.3 and installing 1.5.1 again?
I'm asking because the output window itself and the symbols in the left bottom corner look very blurry, not only the plot

Comment: Let's not mix too many variables here. Can you plot from the command line without any IPython involved? (If you want me to understand "blurry" a screenshot would be helpful)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added a screenshot to the post. The explorer on the right is to show the difference between the "blurry" output that I get from matplotlib and the normal view I used to have. In the image the difference is a little understated because the screenshot is small, but I hope it's still visible enough

Comment: and I don't know how to run the plot without IPython involved because the window always aitomatically opens when I use plt.show()

Comment: So from the screenshot we see that (1) You are successfully using matplotlib 1.5 (2) There is no IPython specific window involved, what you see is the matplotlib TkInter window. (3) Anything that might be blurry here is probably on screen only. If you do `savefig`, the plot should be as clear as ever. What this all means is that this might all be related to your dpiscaling. You might have set your screen to some zoomed value, possibly 125%. This is a [windows functionality](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff629368.aspx).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ok, thanks for the time you took and the explanation; I'll try to change the screen scaling then.
One final question: Why did a matplotlib update change the dpi scaling of my screen when, and only when, displaying plots?

Comment: No it shouldn't. And I cannot be sure of the above, but it looks like the only explanation. Maybe you changed the scaling coincidently around the same time as updating?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Not that I know, but I'll try to figure it out. At least I know now it has nothing to do with matplotlib itself. Thanks :)